# How do I replace matched groups in a regex?

Tags: .net, regex, c++-cli

Given some input data:

```xml
<somexml>
    <User Name="MrFlibble">
        <Option Name="Pass">SomeSaltedPassword</Option>
        <Option Name="Salt">Salt</Option>
        <tag1></tag1>
        <Permissions>
            <Permission Dir="E:"></Permission>
        </Permissions>
    </User>
    <User Name="MrFlobble">
        <Option Name="Pass">SomeOtherSaltedPassword</Option>
        <Option Name="Salt">Salt</Option>
        <tag1></tag1>
        <Permissions>
            <Permission Dir="C:"></Permission>
        </Permissions>
    </User>
</somexml>
```

I'd like to replace the first user that doesn't have a `C:` permission in the user area (in this case `MrFlibble`) with `Jon` and `SomeSaltedPassword` with `MyNewSaltedPassword` using a .net framework regex to give the following result:

```xml
<somexml>
    <User Name="Jon">
        <Option Name="Pass">MyNewSaltedPassword</Option>
        <Option Name="Salt">Salt</Option>
        <tag1></tag1>
        <Permissions>
            <Permission Dir="E:"></Permission>
        </Permissions>
    </User>
    <User Name="MrFlobble">
        <Option Name="Pass">SomeOtherSaltedPassword</Option>
        <Option Name="Salt">Salt</Option>
        <tag1></tag1>
        <Permissions>
            <Permission Dir="C:"></Permission>
        </Permissions>
    </User>
</somexml>
```

I think something like this regex would capture the users and group the sections I Want to replace:

```
<User Name="(.*)">.*<Option Name="Pass">(.*)<\/Option>.*<Option Name="Salt">(.*)<\/Option>.*<\/User>
```

...but I'm struggling to see how I would substitute the three groups while maintaining the other text. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) all seem to suggest replacing modifications of the original text rather than multiple specifically named groups with specific new text.

Is there a standard way to do this or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is evil, and is equivalent to killing a kitten.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. How would you solve it instead then?

Comment: What prevents you from doing a simple substitution? i.e. finding `Name="MrFlibble"` and replacing with `Name="Jon"`

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be `MrFlibble` originally and I don't want to match the entry with `C:` in it. I should have made that clear in the question. Will do so now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not under any circumstances try to parse XML with a regex unless you wish to invoke [rite <sub>6</sub>6<sup>6</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) *Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn.*

Use an XML parsing library see [this page](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/parsing-xml-files-in-net-using-c/184416669) for some ways to do it.

Comment: Second answer down in that first link more closely describes my use case I _think_. This is some well-formed XML in a very closed environment, not scraping some possibly horribly formed XHTML from a random website.

Comment: Took your advice and narrowly closed the gate before it had fully formed. Took -4 sanity in the process and woke up in Arkham Asylum for my trouble though... ...Dr Dobbs got me through it!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite difficult to do with regular expressions because you need a replacement by condition.

In the comment you wrote that it is well-formed xml. Therefore, I dare to offer a solution using xml parser.

Add reference to System.Xml.Linq library to the project.
Open the following namespaces

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Xml::Linq;
```

The code is very simple and concise

```
//auto xml = XElement::Parse(input); // input - string containing your xml
auto xml = XElement::Load(L"test.xml");

for each (auto user in xml->Elements(L"User"))
{
    if (user->Element(L"Permissions")->Element(L"Permission")->Attribute(L"Dir")->Value != L"C:")
    {
        user->Attribute(L"Name")->Value = L"Jon";

        for each(auto option in user->Elements(L"Option"))
        {
            if (option->Attribute(L"Name")->Value == L"Pass")
            {
                option->Value = L"MyNewSaltedPassword";
            }
        }
    }
}

Console::WriteLine(xml);
//xml->Save(L"result.xml");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my platform is limited to .net 2.0 so I was unable to use `Linq`

Answer (score 1):

Option with regular expressions. The expression itself looks obscure, as a result it is difficult to maintain. Therefore, it is better to use the method with the xml parser.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Text::RegularExpressions;
```

MatchEvaluator method:

```
String^ Evaluate(Match^ m)
{
    if (m->Groups[L"dir"]->Value != L"C:")
        return L"Jon" + m->Groups[L"mid1"] + L"MyNewSaltedPassword" + m->Groups[L"mid2"] + m->Groups[L"dir"];
    else
        return m->Groups[L"name"]->Value + m->Groups[L"mid1"] + m->Groups[L"pass"] + m->Groups[L"mid2"] + m->Groups[L"dir"];
}
```

Code:

```
auto input = File::ReadAllText(L"test.xml");

auto pattern = gcnew String(R"(
(?<= <User \s Name = " )
(?'name' .+? )
(?= "> )

(?'mid1' .+? )

(?<= <Option \s Name = "Pass"> )
(?'pass' .+? )
(?= </Option> )

(?'mid2' .+? )

(?<= <Permission \s Dir = " )
(?'dir' .+? )
(?= "> )
)");

auto options = RegexOptions::IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions::Singleline;

auto evaluator = gcnew MatchEvaluator(Evaluate);
auto result = Regex::Replace(input, pattern, evaluator, options);

Console::WriteLine(result);
```